# Dual boot enrolled chromebook

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook

My wife got this Chromebook (Samsung 303C) from work which is enrolled to her educational institution for centralised management. I'm cool with that.

I'd like to install Ubuntu on a SD card to be able to dual boot to that, but I haven't found any clear information on what will happen to the Google Admin Console enrollment if start the device in developer mode and install ChrUbuntu on the SD card. Any ideas?

Also does the recovery USB i created from chrome://imageburner contain the enrollment information or is it just a blank recovery of Chrome OS without any enrollment details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to dual boot the Chromebook the device will have to be put into [Developer Mode](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/poking-around-your-chrome-os-device), this will wipe the device and result in the Enterprise Enrollment being lost.

As far as I'm aware the device *can* be enrolled again whilst in developer mode, but this would most likely need to be completed by an administrator and may not be successful depending on the policies put in place by the management system.

In regards to the question about the recovery USB you have created: No, the USB is created using a standard image that should not contain any information on the state of the Chrome device that was used to create it.

This basically all leads to the security policies in place within the organisation that has provided the laptop. Also be aware of the vulnerabilities that you open a Chrome OS device up to when entering developer mode which can be viewed [here](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chromiumos-design-docs/developer-mode).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This was pretty much what I was suspecting. It really is a pity you can't dual boot _and_ keep the enrollment information.